# Using Excel VBA, open a web page and then save it

Tags: excel, download, vba

I'm trying to write a macro that will open a given URL and perform a File >> SaveAs...  The URL returns an XML output on the screen and I want to save it.  Then I can have Excel open the file and work on it (this part I can do).

Here's basically what I want to do and it works except for the SaveAs bit:

```
Sub Main()
REM Reference to "Microsoft Internet Controls" is being used.
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer

Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

With objIE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "http://exampleURL.comany.com/ServerOutput/XmlFile.xml"
    Do Until .readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    REM The next line fails
    .SaveAs "C:\temp\test.xml"

    .Application.Quit
End With

Set objIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

A plain "Save" is fine if that's all that will work.  Just looking for a way to save the output on the screen.  Thanks!

Comment: Probably because `objIE` doesn't have a `SaveAs` property? Is `GET`ting the XML not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this can help?

```
Public Sub GetXML()

    Dim oXML As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim xURL As String

    'Retrieve XML.
    xURL = "http://exampleURL.comany.com/ServerOutput/XmlFile.xml"
    oXML.Open "GET", xURL, False
    oXML.send

    'Put into sheet.
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = oXML.responseXML.XML

End Sub
```

EDIT: Make sure the reference to `Microsoft XML, v3.0` is enabled for this.

Comment: BK, thanks.  Unfortunately, the user didn't tell me the actual URL won't execute until one logs in first, which can't be done with embedded credentials :-(  Sorry for wasting your time but thank you for your help, I'm sure I'll be able to use this else where.

Comment: I tested with a locally saved file and used that.  Your code didn't work, however, oXML.responseText did contain the text of the file, so that's good.  Anyway, I have another way to read & parse an XML file so I'll use that method.